# unique number of occurrance in a number range

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

I am interested in figuring out how many times each number occurs once in a numberrange of 5 digits, like 01234, 01243,  01324, etc ....
I know that the occurence is 120 unique times
At the moment I have programmed it with a lot of for loops and a lot of ands.
as you can see in the code

```
number = 5
for a in range(number):
    for b in range(number):
        for c in range(number):
            for d in range(number):
                for e in range(number):
                    if (a != b and a != c and a != d and a != e and
                            b != c and b != d and b != e and c != d and 
                            c != e and d != e):
                        print ('{}{}{}{}{}'.format(a, b, c, d, e))
```

Is there a different and a nicer way to program the code above?

Greets,

Superfly

Comment: Are you looking for the number of permutations or the permutations themselves? The number is just n! (n faculty), the permutations can be generated with https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested using itertools. Here is the code to use:

```
from itertools import permutations
#generator
factorials = permutations(set(range(5)))
for fact in factorials:
    print(fact)
```

If you would not like to use itertools, but would like to generate every string, you can use a list comprehension to put it all in one line.

```
rn = range(number)
number= 5

sequences = [(a,b,c,d,e) for a in rn for b in rn for c in rn for d in rn for e in rn if a != b and a!= c and a!= d and a!= e and b!= c and b!=d and b!=e and c!=d and c!= e and d!= e]
```

Alternatively, you could define a method to recursively create new lists and append items

```
def rGenFactorials(L, leng=5, collected = [], restrictions=set()):

    # base case
    if len(L) == leng:
        collected.append(L)
        return

    #induction
    options = set(range(leng))
    options  -= restrictions

    for op in options:

        # copy restrictions
        r = set(restrictions)
        # add new restriction
        r.add(op)

        # copy list
        l = L[:]
        # append unused int
        l.append(op)

        # recursive invocation
        rGenFactorials(L=l,collected = collected, restrictions=r)


C = []
rGenFactorials([], collected = C)
for c in C:
    print(c)
```